# Get QueryString Value from iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I have an iFrame like this:

```
"<iframe src='/tnfse.aspx?id_nfse='" + nota + "' seamless='seamless' class='frame' frameBorder='0' ></iframe>";
```

I have tried a lot of differents way to get this value (id_nfse), but, always a get a NULL EXCEPTION.

The value (nota) is correct, because when I do an alert(nota) I see the parameter correct.

This is how I have tried to get the value:

```
Request.QueryString["id_nfse"]
```

Always NULL...

Tks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a single quote that shouldn't be there:

```
"<iframe src='/tnfse.aspx?id_nfse='" + node + "'...
```

should be

```
"<iframe src='/tnfse.aspx?id_nfse=" + node + "'...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Script

```
$(document).ready(function() 

{ 

var loc = window.location.toString(), 

params = loc.split('?')[1], 

iframe = document.getElementById("trackFrame");   

iframe.src = iframe.src + '?' + params; 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thks guys... This code solve my issue:

```
<iframe src='/tnfse.aspx?id_nfse=" + node + "'>
```